# Why is viewWillDisappear called at the wrong time when using manual view containment?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

This is how I am using the containment API.  According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willMoveToParentViewController:) is its correct.

```
[self.childViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    self.childViewController.view.frame = ... // View Animation
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self.childViewController.view removeFromSuperview]; // triggers `viewWillDisappear`
    [self.childViewController removeFromParentViewController];
}];
```

I expect `viewWillDisappear` to be called before the animation begins and `viewDidDisappear` to be called after the animation completes.  However, they are both called in quick succession after the animation is complete.

Moving `[self.childViewController.view removeFromSuperview];` to the animation block fixes this, but the code looks wrong:

```
[self.childViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    self.childViewController.view.frame = ... // View Animation
    [self.childViewController.view removeFromSuperview]; // triggers `viewWillDisappear`
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self.childViewController removeFromParentViewController];
}];
```

Does anyone know what the proper way to get `viewWillDisappear` to be called at the correct time is?

Comment: The 'correct' time is just before the view is removed from the view hierarchy, which is when it is happening. Perhaps you should explain why you need it to be called when you do, and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer was to use [`– beginAppearanceTransition:animated:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/beginAppearanceTransition:animated:) & `endAppearanceTransition`

> If you are implementing a custom container controller, use this method to tell the child that its views are about to appear or disappear. Do not invoke viewWillAppear:, viewWillDisappear:, viewDidAppear:, or viewDidDisappear: directly.

The corrected code:

```
[self.childViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self.childViewController beginAppearanceTransition:NO animated:YES];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    self.childViewController.view.frame = ... 
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self.childViewController.view removeFromSuperview]; 
    [self.childViewController removeFromParentViewController];
    [self.childViewController endAppearanceTransition];
}];
```

Comment: Typo, I think: the messages to `self.viewController` should instead be sent to `self.childViewController`, as the appearance transition messages are intended to be sent to the child that is being transitioned.

Answer (score 0):

You are not notifying that the childViewController moved to the parentViewController.

```
[yourViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self]
```

And in `[self.childViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];` You are not mentioning who will be the parentViewController. It is a good practice to indicate when the childViewController was added. Then iOS should know when to trigger viewWillDisappear

You are notifying that a viewController will move to a parentViewController but you are not indicating who is the parentViewController if you indicate which the parentViewController is your code will work as expected.

ViewWillDissappear will get fired when the view is ready to leave the parentView. This will happens in the next willLayoutSubviews execution of your parentViewController or viewController depending in the hierarchy of your viewControllers

```
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    [self.childViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
self.childViewController.view.frame = ... // View Animation
    [self.view addSubView:self.childViewController.view];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self.childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
             // triggers `viewWillDisappear`
            [self.childViewController removeFromParentViewController];
        }];
```

Try that

Comment: I dont think this is correct, from the docs..

> If you are implementing your own container view controller, it must call the willMoveToParentViewController: method of the child view controller before calling the removeFromParentViewController method, passing in a parent value of nil.

Comment: Check my edited answer this is how it should be done, I forgot to mentioned that you are moving the frame but you are not adding the childViewController view to any parent View.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Swift version.
It place `beginAppearanceTransition` in animation closure so you get similar behavior like `UINavigationController`: You can adjust animatable view properties in child view controller's `viewWillDisappear` and get animation automatically.

```
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, dampingRatio: 1) {
    childViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
    childViewController.beginAppearanceTransition(false, animated: true)
    childViewController.view.frame = ... // View Animation
}
animator.addCompletion { _ in
    childViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
    childViewController.endAppearanceTransition()
    childViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
}
animator.startAnimation()
```

Notice the `endAppearanceTransition` must be called after `view.removeFromSuperview` otherwise system will send duplicate `viewWillDisappear` `viewDidDisappear` methods to your child view controller.